# how to view closed work items in TFS

Tags: tfs

How can I see closed Work Items in TFS 2010 ? I can see Active & Proposed items but not closed items. Is there any configuration or settings change that I need to do ?

I just accidentally closed a work item. I need to reactivate it again .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find or create the appropriate query in Team Explorer under Work Items -> Queries.